# Server returned HTTP response code: 502 when I try to import a gradle project in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

When I try to import any gradle project in IntelliJ, I get the following error:

> Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL:
> http://myartifactory/gradle/2.8.0.32/gradle-2.8.0.32-bin.zip

where the gradle version is downloaded by my artifactory. And the gradle build fails because of that.

Additional info:

- intellij idea ultimate v. 2020.1;
- I tried several gradle projects but the result is exactly the same;
- I tried to ping the URL directly through the browser and I am able to download the file successfully;
- I found suggestions related to setting a proxy, however this worked just fine with my previous laptop without any additional configs.

Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi,
Do these projects work fine from command line (without intellij idea)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, yes they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue eventually. The issue for me was related to the HTTP Proxy.
The default setting for the HTTP proxy in IntelliJ should be *No proxy*. It turns out instead that inexplicably the Proxy was set to *Manual proxy* and somehow the hostname and port were pointing to a non existing proxy on my network.

In summary you can try the following in the IDE:

- Navigate to **File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior >SYstem Settings > HTTP Proxy**
- Set the proxy to **No proxy**.

While this is the solution in my case, I can see how people could hit the same  because they need a proxy (e.g. on the company network). In that case setting up the proxy to *Auto-detect* or *Manual Proxy configuration* and filling up the details should help solving the issue.